# Excel VBA - Function to detect if a file exists based on Cell Values

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to write a function to detect if a file (pdf) exists.  Due to there being a number of files/folders I'd like to build the filepath from cell values.

I've got this so far:

```
Public Function FileExists(FullpathName As String) As Boolean

If Len(Dir(FullpathName)) = 0 Then

    FileExists = True

Else

    FileExists = False

End If

End Function
```

And I'm entering this in the cell:

```
=FileExists(A2&B2&A3&" "&A1&" "&C2&".pdf")
```

but it's returning it as false when the file is definitely in there. Can anyone shed some light on what I'm missing?

Thankyou!

Comment: Should it not be the other way round (`True` and `False`)?

Comment: have you got the \\'s between the parts of the path?

Comment: `A2&B2&A3&" "&A1&" "&C2&".pdf"` Debug this line and show us what you get for this?

Comment: I've taken out the spaces now as I thought that might be confusing it, the if I put MsgBox FullPathname I get it displaying G:\Spalton\TestDocs\ChrisSpaltonSept121.pdf - which is the correct file, in the correct place but which still returns  false on checking it.  I've never used the DIR command before, do I need to activate an add on or something for it to work?

Answer (score 3):

Your **IF** condition is backwards, use:

```
Public Function FileExists(FullpathName As String) As Boolean
    If Len(Dir(FullpathName)) = 0 Then
        FileExists = False
    Else
        FileExists = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Nope, that still isn't working, could it be something to do with including the \\'s in the cell? for instance A2 currently is G:\Documents\

Comment: You need to do a little debugging...........include this line in your UDF:    **MsgBox FullPathName**

Comment: This works for Excel files, detects those properly and correctly, however still refuses to work for PDF's (which is what I need) how can I get around this?